# Transfer file from local machine to remote machine using SFTP

Tags: ubuntu, sftp

I am using MAC as my local machine and my remote machine is the Ubuntu-AWS machine. I use following command to transfer file to remote machine.I want my python file p1.py to be transferred to remote machine with location /usr/share/

```
sftp -i test1.pem ubuntu@54.xx.xx.xx:/usr/share/  /tmp/p1.py
```

But gave me following error

```
Connected to 54.xx.xx.xx
Fetching /usr/share/ to /tmp/p1.py
Cannot download non-regular file: /usr/share/
```

What could be the possible problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use interactive console by 
**`sftp -i test1.pem ubuntu@54.xx.xx.xx:/usr/share/`** 
and then in console
 **`> put /tmp/p1.py`**

You can also use 
**`scp -i <identity_file> /tmp/p1.py  ubuntu@54.xx.xx.xx:/usr/share/`**.

Make sure you have write access to **`/usr/share`** folder while doing scp.